# If every limit is contained within a set, then does the set contain all its limits points?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was wondering if it has been shown that if every limit of a sequence from a set S is contained within S, then does that mean that S contains all of its limit points?

Comment: This can be shown. It requires a weak version of the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @André: It’s false in general: you need $X$ to be Fréchet-Urysohn.

Comment: I thought the context was real analysis.

Comment: @André: I shouldn’t be surprised, though I’ve seen the tag (mis)used more generally. Still, the unqualified statement seems to me to have considerable potential to mislead.

Comment: @andre: How can this be shown using the weak axiom of countable choice?

Comment: Here we are assuming that we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $a$ be a limit point of $S$. For any ball $B_n$ of radius $\frac{1}{n}$, there is a point $a_n\ne a$, with $a_n\in S$, such that $a_n\in B_n$. Simultaneously choose such an $a_n$ for every $n$. That gives us the required sequence. We have used Dependent Choice (DC), which is not provable from $ZF$. It is an immediate consequence of AC. It can be shown that DC does not imply full AC.

Comment: @JimDarson: Of course the same argument, with no wording change, works in a metric space. Dependent Choice (or Countable Choice) will do the job because the $a_n$ can be chosen one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This is true in metric spaces, more generally in first countable spaces, and even more generally in [Fréchet-Urysohn spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Fr.C3.A9chet.E2.80.93Urysohn_space), so it’s true, for example, in all of the Euclidean spaces $\Bbb R^n$ that you encounter in a first course in real analysis.

It’s false in general, however. Let $X$ be the space $\omega_1+1$ of ordinals $\alpha\le\omega_1$ with the order topology, which can be written $[0,\omega_1]$ in interval notation, and let $S=[0,\omega_1)$ be all of $X$ except the righthand endpoint. Every limit of a sequence from $S$ belongs to $S$, but $\omega_1$ is a limit point of $S$ that is not in $S$. The problem is that in general a set can have limit points that are not limits of sequences from the set.